# How to reference files in subprocess module

Tags: python, package

I have some code that is written in both Python and Go, with the following folder structure below. For example, in `sub_mod_a` in `py_file.py`, there is a function `PyFunction()` that references and runs `go_file.go` locally using the `subprocess` module, as seen below:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ["go", "run", "go_file.go"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── mod                           
|   └── sub_mod_a  
|       ├── py_file.py
|       └── go_file.go          
|   ├── sub_mod_b                 
│   └── sub_mod_c                                      
└── examples
    └── example.ipynb
```

Now, in the Jupyter notebook in `examples/`, I call `PyFunction` by doing

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(0, "..")

from mod.sub_mod_a.py_file import PyFunction

PyFunction()
```

However, the go file doesn't seem to run. I think this may be because the subprocess is starting a process in `..`, which is the root directory. How can I fix this problem so that the user doesn't have to change the reference to `go_file.py` to an absolute one in `py_file.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid messing with `sys.path` and instead supply the current working directory to Popen:

```
import os

proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ["go", "run", "go_file.go"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__)
        )
```

or use use full path to the go file

```
import os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'go_file.go')
proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ["go", "run", path],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
```